# How to find Wifi adapters that support managed+AP combined modes?

Tags: linux, wifi, hardware, access-point

I'm trying to add Wifi to a small single board computer running Linux that doesn't have embedded Wifi, but has USB ports. I also need that computer to be a Wifi access point at the same time as it connects to another router as a client.

I know how to find out if a USB Wifi dongle can do it, through `iw list` in the **valid interface combinations** section. However after buying half a dozen dongles, making sure they all had different chipsets, it turns out none of them can do it.

Is there a way to find out from the Linux sources which chipsets support a managed+AP combinations?

Comment: Google for `valid interface combinations` (lots of hits from help requests in forums), note chipset, find hardware with that chipset. That's how I did it for my hardware. Yes, it's hit and miss; a complete list would be nice... Managed + AP on the same frequency is quite frequent. On different frequencies, it's rare.